# Combining AES-SIV and a password-derived key

Tags: authenticated-encryption, pbkdf-2, siv

I use the following scheme to encrypt and authenticate a 64-byte piece of data $P$:
$$ C = \textrm{AES-SIV}(K, \textit{AAD}, P) $$
where

- $AAD$ is a string of 48 bytes, of which 21 bytes are a random salt $S$.
- $K = \textrm{PBKDF2}_{\textrm{SHA256}}(\textit{password}, S, \ldots)$, where $\textit{password}$ might be reused.

**So, the salt $S$ is both included in the $\textit{AAD}$ and used to derive the 256-bit key $K$ fed to the SIV encryption function.**

(The fact that attackers might observe that the same $P$ is encrypted when the same value for $S$ happens to be generated (however minuscule the odds are) is *not* an issue.)

I have learnt to be very suspicious of any cryptographic construction I myself come up with, and because I have never seen a scheme like this, I have to ask: is there problem with this method? I can't possibly think of one, but that's hardly enough for me to be sure it isn't flawed.

Comment: It's very likely not flawed. But if you already have a large salt (and therefore a fully randomized key or secret) I am wondering why you would use AES-SIV instead of one of the more efficient AEAD modes such as GCM.

Comment: Performance is not really an issue (being conservative is more important, right?), and attackers can observe when a (Key, nonce) pair happens to be reused: this likely happens whenever $S$ is repeated, as users are not likely to change passwords very often and the other $\textit{AAD}$ data is not random. In that case, SIV _might_ only reveal that the same $P$ has been encrypted, instead of completely breaking down like stream cipher modes do.

I understand that repeating $S$ is unlikely (likely after about $2^{84}$ encryptions by my calculations), but I see no gain in using a faster mode.

Comment: SIV is certainly less brittle than GCM, so if you can spare the cycles and the less used / standardized mode it may be a good option. Being less reliant on the RNG is also a good idea. You could consider a memory hard password hash such as scrypt of course (if being conservative is important to you...).

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I would certainly like to use scrypt, but I can't, unfortunately, as the Java crypto library I am working with does not provide it. It actually doesn't provide SIV either, but I found an implementation on GitHub (by [Cryptomator](https://cryptomator.org/)) only relying on said crypto library. Anyway, thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Actually, I just noticed the library _does_ provide scrypt. Silly me.

Comment: Probably a good time to find out. Be warned that different password hash *implementations* may use different character encodings. Be sure to specify one.